# SwiftUI Picker in Form - Index out of Range

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, picker, swiftui-form

When I try to display selected data of the picker in a Text(), there is an error called "Index out of range" occurs.

[image: Image of error message]

However, it works fine when I commented the Text() that display the selected data. Below is the codes for picker in form.

```
struct VMPickerView: View {
    
    @State var vmIndex = 0
    @ObservedObject var stockViewModel = StockViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        
        let allVM = self.stockViewModel.arrKey

        return VStack {
        
            Form {
                
                Section {
                    
                    Picker(selection: $vmIndex, label: Text("Location")) {
                        
                        ForEach(0..<allVM.count, id: \.self) {
                            
                            Text(allVM[$0]).tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                    //Text(allVM[vmIndex])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the image of my application when I commented the "Text(allVM[vmIndex])"

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Below is the codes that I used to retrieve data from firebase and store into the array.

```
class StockViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var itemList = [ItemList]()
    @Published var arrKey = [String]()
    
    init() {
        retrieveAllVM()
    }
    
    func retrieveAllVM() {
        
        var arrKey = [String]()
       
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("VM")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            for items in snapshot.children {
                let itemSnap = items as! DataSnapshot
                let allKey = itemSnap.key
                arrKey.append(allKey)
            }
            self.arrKey = arrKey
            print(self.arrKey)
       })
    }
}
```

*My codes after changes made:

```
class StockViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var itemList = [ItemList]()
    @Published var arrKey = [String]()
    
    func retrieveAllVM() {
        
        var arrKey = [String]()
       
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("VM")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            for items in snapshot.children {
                let itemSnap = items as! DataSnapshot
                let allKey = itemSnap.key
                arrKey.append(allKey)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.arrKey = arrKey
                print(self.arrKey)
            }
            //self.arrKey = arrKey
       })
    }
}
```

```
struct VMPickerView: View {
    
    @State var vmIndex = 0
    @ObservedObject var stockViewModel: StockViewModel

    var body: some View {
        
        let allVM = self.stockViewModel.arrKey

        return VStack {
        
            Form {
                
                Section {
                    
                    Picker(selection: $vmIndex, label: Text("Location")) {
                        
                        ForEach(0..<allVM.count, id: \.self) {
                            
                            Text(allVM[$0]).tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                    //Text(allVM[vmIndex])
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.stockViewModel.retrieveAllVM()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `observeSingleEvent` method looks to be *asynchronous*. Make sure you update your `@Published` properties on the main thread.

Replace:

```
self.arrKey = arrKey
```

with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.arrKey = arrKey
}
```

---

Your code in init will run every time the ViewModel is created.

```
class StockViewModel: ObservableObject {
    ...
    init() {
        retrieveAllVM()
    }
```

You can move calling `retrieveAllVM` to the `.onAppear`:

```
struct VMPickerView: View {
    @State var vmIndex = 0
    @ObservedObject var stockViewModel = StockViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        let allVM = self.stockViewModel.arrKey

        return VStack {
            ...
        }.onAppear {
            self.stockViewModel.retrieveAllVM()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively don't create a ViewModel directly in the `VMPickerView`. Create the ViewModel int the parent view and pass it to the `VMPickerView`:

```
struct VMPickerView: View {
    @State var vmIndex = 0
    @ObservedObject var stockViewModel: StockViewModel // pass only
    ...
}
```

---

Or, if you're using SwiftUI 2.0, you can use a `@StateObject`:

```
struct VMPickerView: View {
    @State var vmIndex = 0
    @StateObject var stockViewModel = StockViewModel()
    ...
}
```

---

### EDIT

Dealing with indices is risky. If for any other reason your code fails, try to use `if` or `guard` statements to make sure you never access the invalid index.

Instead of:

```
Form {
    Section {
        ...
        Text(allVM[vmIndex])
    }
}
```

you can add in the picker view a computed property returning the current key view:

```
@ViewBuilder
var currentKeyText: some View {
    if vmIndex < stockViewModel.arrKey.count {
        Text(stockViewModel.arrKey[vmIndex])
    }
}
```

and access it like this:

```
Form {
    Section {
        ...
        currentKeyText
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like the result is still the same.

Comment: I tried the first 3 solutions, the last solution is not applicable for me because I am not using SwiftUI 2.0.

Comment: I applied your solution but the result is still the same. I printed out the data that I got from the array --> ["Bukit Jalil", "Sri Petaling"] and I don't see any problem with that array.

Comment: @BingoLingo There is no problem with your view or the array itself. I ran your code without the firebase stuff and it was working fine. The general rule is to wrap every update of `@Published` property in `DispatchQueue.main.async` (if it's being updated in the background). And better NOT to rely on the ViewModel init - SwiftUI may refresh the view and reload your ViewModel - which will cause the `retrieveAllVM` to fire. Use `.onAppear` in the view instead.

Comment: I used .onAppear to call the func instead of init() but the result is the same.

Comment: @BingoLingo And did you use `DispatchQueue.main.async` as well? This is not an alternative, it's a *must*.

Comment: @BingoLingo I'm not sure what else might be breaking for you. The code you provided (without firebase) works fine. I added a safe getter for your `Text` field. This should stop your crashes.